Why does function not take the ownership of Option<T> argument?
I test the code below:
fn main() {
    let tested = Some(5);
    testoption(tested);
    println!("the tested is {}", tested.unwrap());
}

fn testoption(p: Option<i32>) {
    println!("the argument is {}", p.unwrap());
}

The variable tested can be used after the function is called. I thought it should be moved.
So, what kind of variable would not be moved after the function call? Implement the Copy trait Or something else?

Rust options implement the Copy trait if the wrapped type implement Copy. Types which implement this trait are copied on assignment and not moved, which is why tested can still be accessed after calling the testoption function.

Thanks. I visited that URL before but neglect the condition where T: Copy.
